# Rails caches_action and cache_path: ensuring that cache paths are unique for action and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I'm using `caches_action` like so:

```
caches_action :index, :show,
              :expires_in => 10.minutes,
              :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params.merge(format: c.request.format).except('gclid') }
```

This is to ensure that for a given action the request parameters are also considered when caching, so that requests like `?page=1` are distinct from `?page=2`.

But I'm concerned that by replacing the default path I'm not providing enough information. If I am caching multiple actions (e.g. `show` and `index`) do I need to also specify the action in my `cache_path` proc? Do I need to throw the controller name in there? Or is the return value of my proc merely appended to some sensible default path that already contains these things?

The documentation mentions that the result of the proc "will be passed directly to ActionCachePath.path_for", but perhaps that's out of date because I don't see any `path_for` method in ActionCachePath.

Comment: action caches are really nasty. it's nearly impossible to get things right. especially if you have multi-tenancy or mutli-language apps. from my perspective it makes more sense to use ETAGs or/and cache partials.

Comment: How is etags helpful? Won't that just tell the client to cache the result once received? I'm using caches_action to cache an expensive operation so it can be served to many clients. For multi-language you can do layout: false and then render translations in the view.

Comment: it's very useful in combination with a reverse proxy. i think this link is a little old, but never the less... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UvpMhzkktw